# Private key algorithm is not compatible with signature algorithm

Tags: android, ionic-framework

As I used `keytool` to check for the key details, it says keystore contains 2 entries.

Signature algorithm for one of them is `SHA1withDSA` and `SHA256withRSA` for another one.

I used the command

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore 
my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

to sign my apk. but it gives the error that says:

> Private key algorithm is not compatible with signature algorithm

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

just removing -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Add below 2 lines inside `project.ant.genkey` if using Android studio

```
sigalg: 'MD5withRSA',
keyalg: 'RSA'
```

Comment: It's an ionic project. Not using Android studio.I have used git bash command line to execute the commands.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem when generating a new keystore file then I used the new keystore file to sign myApp.apk
I generated the key using:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myApp_keystore.jks android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk myApp_alias -keypass MY_KEYPASS -storepass MY_STOREPASS
```

Answer (score 0):

So just use one of the signature algorithms of the keys you have there... either

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withDSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

or

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```